# why can't I overwrite a CSS file that has been added to the head using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to overwrite styles that have been linked to the head of the HTML file by Javascript. I am putting the styles I want to overwrite into a  tag in the body of the HTML file but it only overwrites if I use !important, whereas I can overwrite CSS that I manually link into the head of the page before any Javascript has loaded.

I have tried to overwrite the styles using !important and adding the styles inline to the element itself which both work.

Comment: Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

It's not possible to say precisely without seeing your code, but this likelly a cascading/priority/specificity issue.
You can only overwrtite them with `!important` or inline styles, because the styles you want to overwrite have higher priority than your own styles. The `!important` flag changes this priority in a similar way, inline styles also have higher priority in CSS compared to other selectors.

You can read more here: https://blogs.halodoc.io/best-practices-that-we-follow-to-avoid-specificity-issues/

Comment: Maybe the downvoter wants to leave a comment as well?